# Placement of checkbox label

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I want the check box label to appear before the checkbox. The issue is, I can't make use of the attribute for="checkbox id" in label, unless the label comes after the check box. I strictly need to use the combination of check box and label, i.e. I can't use nested label or a check box with < p> or < span> before it. Can someone aid in this. Thank you.

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" />
<label for="chk1">I agree</label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just switch the order of the two lines

```html
<label for="chk1">I agree</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="chk1" />
```

Comment: Thanks mate. It turns out that label css is over sizing to cover the check box. I dint try to switch them because I thought that the for attribute in label can't come before the check box. Thanks again.